# Having issue every time I open android studio. Getting error: Gradle 'MyExpenses2' project refresh failed. What should I do?

Tags: settings, system-error, application-error

[image: Error seen when android studio is started.]

Every time i open android studio i get the following error:
Gradle 'MyExpenses2' project refresh failed
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

I am not able to proceed with my project. What should I do?
I tried many different solutions like invalidating cache, installing different sdk tools and updating sdk tools but nothing works.

Comment: I dont even know why i am getting this error.

Comment: I believe this belongs on Stack Overflow, rather than Android Enthusiasts.